# Angular Ionic Capacitor | Why is Even a Simple Animation Laggy

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, animation, css-animations, capacitor

I'm building a simple Ionic Capacitor app with Angular.

The app includes a few pretty simple animations, and I'm stunned to learn these animations are incredibly laggy:

In the app, I have a list of contacts.
When a contact is selected, the height of a div above the list is increased, and the list below is pushed down. Please refer to screenshots below.

This animation is implemented using Ionic's own [animation library](https://ionicframework.com/docs/utilities/animations):

```
await this.animationController
    .create()
    .iterations(1)
    .addElement(document.querySelectorAll('.selected-contacts'))
    .duration(150)
    .fromTo('height', '0, '160px').play();
```

Simplified HTML:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="selected-contacts"><!-- some stuff here --></div>
   <div class="list"> 
      <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport> 
        <!-- List here --> 
      </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport> 
   </div>
</div>
```

Playing this animation does the job, but its noticeable laggy, both on a new iPhone Pro and an older Android (pretty much same amount of lagging).

**Question:**

 A simple height animation should not be laggy on a new iPhone, what am I doing wrong? Could it be that the underlying OS is only allocating a tiny fraction of resources to and Ionic Capacitor application? What am I missing here?

**Disclaimer:**

I know using `translate`, `transform` uses less CPU/GPU since the DOM is not rewritten here, but I still have a hard time to accept that a new iPhone cannot animate a height change without being laggy.

[image]

Comment: I am also facing performance issue on android devices but IOS is working okay for me. https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/discussions/3899

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animation the height property in any framework is not performant. Height requires the browser to need to re-layout the entire page and will always cause jank.

See [CSS-Triggers](https://csstriggers.com/height) for more details.

Using something like Transforms/Translate3D instead to create the effect you're looking for.

*EDIT*

Adding a link to a [past talk from Liam DeBeasi](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A5a15NrcGoM) about animations and performance.

Comment: Migrated to Flutter, animations works much better. Ionic was a poor choice for my project. Still love Ionic, but it's just not useable for large apps with lots of animations.

Comment: Would you mind just marking this as correct, as this was the cause of your original issue? Off topic, I'd argue that Ionic is good with animations (as we have a bunch in the framework internally), just animations need to use correct properties (transform and opacity) and not things like height/width which are going to cause jank.